# Symbol's value as variable is void: erlang-xemacs-p

Tags: emacs, erlang

I added a Wrangler plugin for Erlang in Emacs (Windows) and every time I start it I get this error:

```
Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading ‘c:/Users/ecotjos/AppData/Roaming/.emacs’:

Symbol's value as variable is void: erlang-xemacs-p
```

This is my `.emacs` file:

```
(setq load-path (cons  "C:\\Users\\ecotjos\\erl10.6\\lib\\tools-3.3\\emacs" load-path))
(setq erlang-root-dir "C:\\Program Files\\erl10.4\\usr")
(setq exec-path (cons "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\erl10.1\\bin" exec-path))
(require 'erlang-start)
(require 'cc-mode)
(add-to-list 'load-path
             "C:\\Users\\ecotjos\\erl10.6\\Wrangler\\elisp")
(require 'wrangler)
```

Comment: Are you using `emacs` or `xemacs`?

Comment: Have you asked for help from the maintainers of the wrangler plugin? If this problem started after you added that it seems likely to be the cause of the error. Perhaps there is more setup you need to do to use it, or it may be incompatible with your version fo (X)Emacs.

Comment: Just a guess - but perhaps this is a relevant issue of the Wrangler package: https://github.com/RefactoringTools/wrangler/issues/84

Comment: I recommend you try `emacs --debug-init` which should give you (or us) more info about the source of the problem.

Comment: I am using emacs on windows with erlang plugin which is working ok. Will try --debug-init to see what's happening in more detail. One interesting thing is that after the emacs is up I hit ctrl-c-ctrl-r to enable Wrangler, and I can see in the console that the plugin is starting, but it fails with "Symbol's value as variable is void: erlang-xemacs-p".

Answer (score 0):

As noted in [this bug report](https://github.com/RefactoringTools/wrangler/issues/84), Wrangler depends on a variable that has been removed from recent versions of erlang-mode.  The quick fix for this is to add this piece of code to your `.emacs` file:

```lisp
(defconst erlang-xemacs-p (string-match "Lucid\\|XEmacs" emacs-version)
  "Non-nil when running under XEmacs or Lucid Emacs.")
```